# Performance problems in Python: os.walk() + filecmp.dircmp().report_full_closure()

Tags: python

I currently have a need to compare directories after incremental data migrations occur.  I wrote a python script to iterate through a list of source/destinations, perform the incremental copy from source to destination, then immediately compare the number of files and folders in each directory.  To do this comparison, we very simply use:

> for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(destd):
>
> destFileCount += len(files)
>
> destDirCount += len(dirs)

If the number of files/dirs returned are different, we call another section of code to see what exactly is different.  To do that, we run the following and send the output to a file:

> filecmp.dircmp(sourced, destd).report_full_closure()

We use the report_full_closure piece as I'm not aware of another way to do a recursive comparison.  The script then searches the resulting file for lines starting with "only in" and prints them to the screen, effectively showing us the differences.

However inefficient, this works like a charm on directories with under 90,000 files or so but once we hit that upper limit the script becomes sluggish to the extent that it isn't feasible to use it for this purpose.  I suppose my questions can be separated into the following:

1. Am I making a logical error in using both of these modules [os.walk + filecmp.dircmp().report_full_closure()]? i.e., am I really saving time being able to skip the filecmp, or should I just only do the filecmp and skip the file/dir count altogether?
2. Is there any way to combine these two functions by sort of 'caching' the files from one for use in the other?
3. Is there a quicker way to perform either of these functions?  I've searched high and low, so I'm guessing there is not.

I really appreciate your thoughts on this matter.  This script has morphed and grown considerably so please forgive me if the answer is extremely obvious...
Thank you,
M

Comment: Are you only interested in new files and directories? `dircmp` compares the contents of the existing files too.

Comment: Well essentially after performing a migration there should ideally be no differences between source and destination (unless, of course, someone wrote some data to the source during the migration itself), so I'd like to know if there are any differences whatsoever prior to officially 'cutting over' from source to destination.

Comment: But you only do the full comparison if the total number of files or directories is different? I don't understand that part if you are looking for any differences whatsoever.

Comment: It is based on the (potentially incorrect) assumption that the count of the files/folders is considerably faster than the comparison.  If that's the case, we'd save time by not doing a comparison on directories that have the same number of files/folders.  That's part of my question, I suppose--is the difference in the time it takes to perform those two functions negligible such that I should ONLY run the full comparison?

Comment: Also, thank you for the comments Janne!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
dir_diff = filecmp.dircmp(sourced, destd)
if dir_diff.left_only or dir_diff.right_only:
    dir_diff.report_full_closure()
```

EDIT: 
Here is a [nice blog about filecmp module](http://bip.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/filecmp/index.html).

There could be 2 reasons why the differences returned by dircmp are not accurate:
1. It uses os.stat to compare the files (shallow comparison), which is good most of the time, but your requirement may be different.
2. Funny files - renaming file to a directory, etc are shown under common. So, you need to consider dir_diff.common_funny as well. Here is the modified code:

```
dir_diff = filecmp.dircmp(sourced, destd)
if dir_diff.left_only or dir_diff.right_only or dir_diff.common_funny:
    dir_diff.report_full_closure()
```

Comment: That is an interesting thought, I'll do some testing on that today.  Thanks very much for your suggestion!

Comment: Basically, we can calculate the directory difference only once instead of twice as in original case (first using os.walk and second time using filecmp.dircmp).

Comment: Salil, looking back, wouldn't this only perform a recursive comparison [report_full_closure()], IF one of the top-level files/folders was different between the source and destination?

Comment: My understanding is the difference is calculated only once when you create the object using dircmp. left_only, right_only and report_full_disclosure merely represent it in different forms.

Comment: Hi Salil.  Hadn't been able to look at this for awhile but after making this change, the script will only return differences if a top-level directory is different.  Once I added a couple files to a subfolder (thus creating a difference between sourced and destd), the script will treat the source and destination as identical.  Any thoughts on this?  Perhaps I'm implementing your suggestion too basically (my implementation is essentially as you stated above).  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the added info!  Unfortunately, I'm fairly certain that dircmp on its own uses a shallow comparison.  Oh well...thanks again!